# Flask WTForm validation

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms

I have added validation using built-in rules in WTForms. However, the validation fails. It's not showing the message for the email field and accepting any random strings in the textbox. How can I test that validation is working?

```
from flask import Flask, app, render_template, request
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField, SubmitField, validators
from wtforms.fields.simple import PasswordField 
from wtforms.validators import Email, InputRequired, length, EqualTo


app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['SECRET_KEY']="PQrs12t46uv"

class MyForm(FlaskForm):
    email = StringField(label=('Email Id'), validators=[ InputRequired("Enter the valid email address"), Email(), length(min=6, max=10)])
    password=PasswordField(label="Password", validators=[InputRequired()])
    confirm_password=PasswordField("Confirm Password", validators=[EqualTo('password',message="Should be same as the password.")])
    submit = SubmitField(label=('Register'))  

@app.route('/')
def base():
    form = MyForm()
    return render_template('formvalidation.html', form=form)

@app.route('/submitform', methods=["GET","POST"])
def submitform():
    if request.method == 'POST':
         return 'form accepted successfully.'

if __name__=="__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

```
# formvalidation.html

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head><title>My website</title></head>
    <body>
        <h1>Login form</h1>  
        <form action="http://127.0.0.1:5000/submitform" method="post">
        <p>{{form.email.label}}: {{form.email}}</p>
        <p>{{form.password.label}}: {{form.password}}</p>
        <p>{{form.confirm_password.label}}: {{form.confirm_password}}</p>
        <p>{{form.submit}}</p> 
    </form>
      
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `submitform` function,

```
@app.route('/submitform', methods=["GET","POST"])
def submitform():
    if request.method == 'POST':
         return 'form accepted successfully.'
```

`request.method == 'POST'` will only check if the form was submitted, not if the credentials were validated. To ensure that the validation works, you could add the conditional, `if form.validate():`. This would return 'True' if the validations were met. A shortcut I use is `if form.validate_on_submit():`. This checks that the form has been submitted and that the validations were met with one conditional, instead of checking that the method is equal to 'POST' and that the form has been validated. Note that you will need to define this 'form' variable that holds the desired Flask form. The following function should work.

```
@app.route('/submitform', methods=["GET","POST"])
def submitform():
    form = MyForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
         return 'form accepted successfully.'
```